# Bypass WebView crossdomain security

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview, cross-domain

#### Scenary

- A Cocoa application with a WebView element that loads *file:///index.html*
- A local resource *file:///index.html* that has an editable iframe with *src="javascript:;"*
- The editable iframe contains another iframe with *src="file:///resource.html"*

#### Problem

It seems that WebView does not allow loading local resources (*resource.html*) inside documents that are not local (iframe with *src="javascript:;"*).

This is the exact message from the Error Console of Safari for MacOSX:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///resource.html
```

#### Question

Do you know any way to bypass this security check? I can modify all the javascript and Cocoa code, but I preffer to modify only the Cocoa code.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I downloaded the source code of WebKit, inserted a *return true* in the certain place to disable these security measures and compiled it.

It seems that it works.